# Percentages and fractions in a will?

Tags: united-kingdom, wills

My wife and I are considering writing a will (in UK), and I have looked for general advice online. I get the impression that we have to specify how much cash should be granted to each heir; but that seems odd to me. After all, one may own property, but the value is always going to be a guess until it is sold - isn't it possible to specify percentages - as in '50% go to ..., 30% to ... ' etc? It seems obvious to me that it must be that way, but I haven't come across it so far.

Comment: Personal anecdote - my ex-wife's grandmother had told her a number of times that she stood to benefit handsomely from her inheritance. Unfortunately, grandmother had not considered the rising cost of living nor the cost of medical care as she aged. In her will she had allocated certain fixed amounts to a handful of friends & charities, with the balance left to her granddaughter (expecting this balance to be a significant sum) - but once those fixed amounts had been paid out there was very little left over. Probably less than a 1/10th the amount she had been expecting to leave for her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* (and usually do) specify percentages for anything. In the case of real estate, the heirs do not receive a portion of the cash (unless you set it up that way), they receive a specified interest, for example each heir has a 1/3 interest in the property. There may be some complexity to doing that if the heirs hate each other and seek to spitefully punish the others. Normally, the heirs would cooperatively decide e.g. to turn the castle into a B&B and split the costs and profits evenly, but maybe one heir wants the cash. There are resolutions in that case, such as negotiating to buy out the cash-seeking heir's interest, but that is separate from (a consequence of) sharing interest in real estate. An alternative would be for you to anticipate this problem and give Lulu the castle, but giving the cash to Xenophon and the stocks to Kim.

On occasion there can be a problem of dividing indivisible property (non-hypothetically, a requirement to transfer whole shares not fractional shares, resulting in a requirement to say who gets the remainder share). This can be decided by the executor, or can be anticipated by the donor with a specification that the remainder goes to Lulu.

Answer (score 5):

In my twenty-five years of experience writing wills and trusts (and spending time as a professor of estate planning), percentages and fractions are the norm in will writing, and sums certain are the exception, usually used only for small specific gifts to non-family members or distant relatives.